# Why is an immutable variable getting changed by React's state machine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array  `const defaultButtons = [{on: false},{on: false},{on: false}]`
. I also have a Component called Keyboard (the keyboard has 3 buttons). I want its `state.buttons` to default to the defaultButtons array. 
So I set state.buttons to defaultButtons, but every time I change the state, it also changes the defaultButtons array. 
Can I in some way pass the defaultButtons array to React's state machine, without letting it change the original?

```
    const defaultButtons = [{on: false},{on: false},{on: false}];

    class Keyboard extends Component {
      state = {
        buttons: defaultButtons
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({buttons: [{on: true},{on: true},{on: true}]}) // changed buttons
        console.log(defaultButtons) // [{on: true},{on: true},{on: true}] ?!?!? WTF
      }

      render(
        return(<div />)
      )

    }
```

Comment: Some code may clarify the issue you're experiencing...

Comment: We need a little bit example code to understand the issue correctly

Comment: I updated the post with code

Comment: When you set state, you should pass an object to the method: `{ buttons: [{on: true}, {on: true}, {on: true}] }`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I AM doing that, just had a typo in this example code. the project is pretty huge and it took me a long time to find this issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not the code you run yourself, which makes it a bit harder to debug.

```
this.setState(buttons: [{on: true},{on: true},{on: true}]); // Syntax error
```

Because `fn(buttons: [...])` is not a valid way to write javascript.
I guess what you are doing in your code, is

```
this.setState(buttons = [{on: true},{on: true},{on: true}]);
```

Which I can understand, because javascript is confusing sometimes.
To make the error here clearer, you could rewrite the code as

```
let argument = buttons = [{on: true},{on: true},{on: true}]
this.setState(argument);
```

Which is functionally exactly the same as the `(buttons = [...])` code.

You have to use `{}` to indicate that what you are sending into `setState` is an object, like this:

```
this.setState({ buttons: [{on: true}, {on: true}, {on: true}] });
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the example. This is not the problem check line 10 for the issue.

Comment: It's just not true. If you use the code you posted in here, it does not update the variable: https://codesandbox.io/s/q6zv31j2w

Comment: That's because setState is asyncronous. It console logs before the state is set. In my app the conditions are a bit different. But you are right.

Comment: @jeyko, I've updated the sandbox to log after the state has been changed https://codesandbox.io/s/7w31q0on1 It still doesn't produce the bug you describe

Comment: @jeyko Even when console.log-ing the defaultButtons in render does never yield a different value https://codesandbox.io/s/k3y50qxrm3

Comment: I have no idea why it's happening in my app

Comment: @jeyko Can you log the value of defaultButton **before** the render as well? I am quite sure that the setState does not actually change it itself, so it must be something else in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently passing a reference to the defaultButtons variable as an initial state. If you clone the defaultButtons array you won't update the defaultButtons variable when changing the state:

```
  state = {
    buttons: [...defaultButtons],
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, was too quick to answer. This does not work. setState still changes the const variable

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue with the same code as you provided in your question, without my answer.
In my case the `defaultButtons` variable is still the same. And my state has buttons with `true`.